# I cannot activate my ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates)

Tags: 11.10, drivers, graphics, fglrx

I have recently have upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and I have not been able to activate by ATI Radeon Mobility HD5400 driver. I have been able to activate the ATI/AMD propreitary FGLRX graphics driver using the AMD wiki, but I cannot activate the (post-release update) driver. When I try to install through the additional driver's utility I get

> Sorry, installation of this driver failed.
>
> Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

I have looked all over the internet and almost everyone says to use the command

> sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates

When I use this though, my driver is no longer recognized as being active and I am back to square one. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: FGLRX as showed by Jockey is Catalyst Version 11.8, the post release update ***WAS*** version 11.9 (I think they removed them) the newest one from AMD is 11.12, download the one from the AMD site.

Answer (score 1):

FGLRX as showed by Jockey is Catalyst Version 11.8, the post release update WAS version 11.9 (I think they removed them) the newest one from AMD is 11.12, download the one from the AMD site.

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx